# The progress bar on Area 51 isn't full yet

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, beta

The progress bar on Area 51 isn't full yet. Is this a bug?

[image]

The sidebar of its proposal says it is in public beta already:

[image]

Comparing to other full sites which are still in beta phase:

[image]

Take [Computational Science Education](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators) for example. Not all disciplines are excellence, yet the bar is full already.

Comment: Should it _be_ full? I think "full" means a site has graduated, or that it completed 90 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It fills up based on time, not any other metric that I've seen. Betas at 90+ days have full bars. You can see that reflected in the info box text

> Sites remain in beta for at least 90 days to build up a critical mass of users, questions, and participation.

We are only at 70 days, as the number in the blue box on the left states.

It seems that you are confused because you think that *being* in beta would be indicated by a full bar. This isn't the case. Beta starts when you hit the second internal bar and is full after 90 days in beta.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

The progress bar is not full because this site has not completed 90 days in public beta yet.

In case of graduated sites, the progress bar is full and instead of public beta in the end, there is beta. See this.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

What the box actually says is that every site must stays in public beta for at least 90 days before being accepted to be graduated, not this site has already past 90 days. The actual stats are below it:

[image]

Comment: Not sure how that is misleading? We are still in public beta.

Comment: That box is misleading by saying (1) the site is in public beta, and (2) to be able in public beta, it must remain 90 days, hence implicitly says that the site has past 90 days.

Comment: No, that's not what the box says.... the box says that the site is currently in public beta and that it must be **in public beta** for 90 days. The end result is becoming a full site. What is actually unclear is that they really include private beta in that 90 day count, not only public beta.

Comment: Ah I see. What it actually says is that every site must stays in public beta for at least 90 days before being accepted to be graduated. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, though the term "graduate" is something the CMs are trying to reduce usage of. See the links here: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1625/36